# passing query in next link pagination - php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I created a next and previous button in order to filter results 15 per page, it worked perfectly well until i added an sql query that filtered the results out. I noticed that in the url the query string was not attached so i tried to manipulate the next link so that it will show results when clicked, but still nothing (just a blank page)...heres how what i did to the next link:

```
$gap = $numRows - $startrow;

if ($gap >=15)

//now this is the next link..
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+15).'?category='.$category.'" style="float:right">Next</a>'.'  ';
```

i added the category part, which gets its value from the category that the user selects, it displays a correct url when i click next but show a blank page of results.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo; the second ? should be &

```
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$startrow+15).'&category='.$category.'" style="float:right">Next</a>'.'  ';
```

This should work

Comment: thanks alot, that definately solved the issue

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it just needs a clean look from someone else..